# after passing event in function event.preventDefault() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault

```
<div id="address" class="col s12">
            <div class="row">
              <form method="post" action="" id="addressDetails">
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                  <textarea id="lAddress" name = 'lAddress' minlength='20' maxlength='100' class="materialize-textarea" class="validate" required length="100"></textarea>
                  <label for="lAddress" data-error="Must be between 20 to 100 Characters">Local Address</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input-field col s6">
                  <textarea id="pAddress" name = 'pAddress' minlength='20' maxlength='100' class="materialize-textarea" class="validate" required length="100"></textarea>
                  <label for="pAddress" data-error="Must be between 20 to 100 Characters">Permanent Address</label>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="row center-align">
              <button type="submit" name="submitAddress" form="addressDetails" class="waves-effect waves-light light-blue darken-1 btn updateProfile">Save Address Details</button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

HTML and JavaScript Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").on('click', '.updateProfile', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This is my javascript. I simplified it keep it short. My `event.preventDefault()` is not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: it releoads the page.

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: @RahulKumar Probably you have a syntax error in the page, so your JavaScript fails to execute?

Comment: @RahulKumar You must post some html and js. why should a button just refresh the page on click?

Comment: How to check ? It just refresh the complete page

Comment: Please post your HTML code.

Comment: Use `preserve` option in your browser's console. It shows previous page's errors even after refreshing.

Comment: Added HTML Code too

Comment: I used `preserve`. I got this `Navigated to http://127.0.0.1/~rahulcomp/project/profile.php`

Comment: @nicael I added more details to question.

Comment: @VisioN how to check ?

Comment: Add a console log message to the handler and see whether it is getting called

Comment: Is your html loaded dynamically? If so, the button might not exist when you try attach the event to it.

Comment: @RahulKumar You have different problem. Please check the answer below.

Comment: @VisioN got it. Thanks..

Comment: @RahulKumar You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your HTML markup `<button>` element already has class `updateProfile`, so your code should look like that:

```
$('button.updateProfile').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

In your case passing `.updateProfile` as a second argument of `on` method binds `click` event to the element with class `updateProfile` **inside** `<button>` element in a [delegated way](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Answer (score 1):

You have binded your `click` handler in incorrect way.

Try this code instead:

```
$(".updateProfile").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```